# count elements of nested lists of a list python

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of lists of tokens of noun phrase chunks:

```py
NP = [["The dog"], ["it"], ["black car"], ["one cow"], ["the gift in the box"]]
```

I need to count the number of tokens inside each list. So, `NP[0]` is `[The dog]`, and `"the dog"` is two tokens. How can I count this for every element in the nested lists?

Comment: Are all the words in the lists of list meant to be strings or variables?

Comment: Pls post a valid Python data structure (one that can be copied and pasted into a console) and show the exact output you would expect for the given input.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the lists and use `len()`:

```py
>>> NP = [["The", "dog"], ["it"], ["black", "car"], ["one", "cow"], ["the", "gift", "in", "the", "box"]]

>>> [len(x) for x in NP]
[2, 1, 2, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you have provided,  a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that utilizes [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) should work:

```
>>> NP = [["The dog"], ["it"], ["black car"], ["one cow"], ["the gift in the box"]]
>>> token_counts = [len(nested[0].split()) for nested in NP]
>>> token_counts
[2, 1, 2, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant  [['The dog'], ['it'], ['black car'], ['one cow'], ['the gift in the box']]

```
num_of_tokens = [len(np[0].split()) for np in NP]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use actual code examples so people can help you more precisely.

It is unclear, whether your elements are strings or lists with a single string.

Mapping a lambda function, you can `split()` each element into tokens and take `len()` to get the number of tokens.
This will return a list of integers, showing the number of tokens per string

```
NP = [["The dog"], ["it"], ["black car"], ["one cow"], ["the gift in the box"]]
lengthlist = list(map(lambda text:len(text[0].split()), NP))
```

where `lengthlist = [2, 1, 2, 2, 5]`

Comment: Don't (ever) combine `map` and `lambda`, at least not when you are converting it into a list anyway. A comprehension is not only shorter, but more readable and instructive.